# $P(z)=z^4+4z^3-3z^2+20z-40$ . $ i\sqrt{5}$ is one of the roots of $P(z)=0$, find the other roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

Trying to find *'in simplified form, the exact values of the remaining roots'* (I don't know if this is the right track or not) so far I've tried:

If $i\sqrt{5}$ is a root, then its complex conjugate $ -i\sqrt{5}$ is also a root. These two roots mutilplied is $z^2=5$.

I have then divided $P(z)=z^4+4z^3-3z^2+20z-40$ by $z^2=5$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{$z^2$} & \text{$+4z$} & \text{$+3$} \\
\hline
z^2 & z^4 & +4z^3 & +3z^2 \\
+5 & 5z^2 & +20z &  \\
\end{array}
$$

But I think ive gone wrong here as when checking I did $(z^2+4z+3)(z^2+5)$ which equals $z^4+4z^3+8z^2+15$ instead of $z^4+4z^3-3z^2+20z-40$

Comment: So redo the calculation. Why post this on stack ?

Comment: $z^2 = -5$  and $\frac {z^4  + 4z^3 - 3z^2 + 20 z - 40}{z^2 + 5} = z^2 +4z - 8$

Comment: In your calculation, assuming I understand it, you should have $-3z^2$, not $3z^2$.  Then somehow the $5z^2$ term needs to get subtracted, leaving you $-8$ in the quotient

Comment: Ummmm.... because I don't know where I went wrong so am asking for help @ReneSchipperus. Be helpful or don't comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

$$z^4+4z^3-3z^2+20z-40 = (z^2-8)(z^2+5)+4z(z^2+5)= (z^2+5)(z^2+4z-8)$$

So $z_{3,4}= -2\pm 2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: One more: surely these other roots are real?

Comment: How did you get from $z^2+4z-8$ to $-2 \pm 2\sqrt3 i$ ? Could you just explain that step please? @JohnWatson

Answer (score 0):

$P(z)=z^4+4z^3-3z^2+20z-40$

$= z^4 + 5z^2 - 8z^2 - 40 + 4z^3 + 20z$

$= z^2(z^2 + 5) - 8(z^2 + 5) + 4z(z^3 + 5)$

$= (z^2 + 4z -8)(z^2 + 5)$.

So you did some factoring wrong.

Then other two roots can be gotten by the quadratic formula.

($z = \frac {-4 \pm \sqrt{16 + 32}}2= \frac {-4\pm 4\sqrt{3}}2=-2\pm 2\sqrt 3$.

.... I don't entirely understand what this:

$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{$z^2$} & \text{$+4z$} & \text{$+3$} \\
\hline
z^2 & z^4 & +4z^3 & +3z^2 \\
+5 & 5z^2 & +20z &  \\
\end{array}$ is supposed to mean.

the way I'd see it is as:

$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{$z^2$} & \text{$+4z$} & \text{$-8$} \\
\hline
z^2 + 5 & z^4 & +4z^3 & -3z^2 & +20z & -40\\
 & z^4 & & 5z^2  &  \\
\hline
& & 4z^3 &-8z^2& +20z &-40\\
& & 4z^3 & & +20z \\
\hline
& & &  -8x^2 & & -40\\
& & &  -8x^2 & & -40\\
\end{array}$

Comment: They're both the same thing. I was taught your method for ADD maths and the other method for Further maths. I just find the top table a little easier :)

Comment: They obviously are the same thing if they got different answers.  Why is $+3z^2$ a pluse when the polyinomial was $-3z^2$.  And what are you doing with the $5z^2$.  Shouldn't it be combined with the $-3z^2$ somehow.  And what are the $20z$ and $4z^3$ being handled?

Comment: I got a different answer from making a mistake, I read $+3z^2$ instead of $-3z^2$

Comment: Well, obviously.  That's what my answer was pointing out.  They aren't same thing if one was wrong and the other wasn't wrong.

Comment: No I'm saying my method was only wrong because I made a mistake not because the method itself gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was mistaking $-3z^2$ for $+3z^2$ instead. The division should look like:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{$z^2$} & \text{$+4z$} & \text{$-8$} \\
\hline
z^2 & z^4 & +4z^3 & -8z^2 \\
+5 & 5z^2 & +20z &  \\
\end{array}
$$

Then from $z^2+4z-8$ you can complete the square giving $-2\pm\sqrt12$, the other two roots.